# Best way to call Web API in MVC framework

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm completely new to APS.NET core and MVC here.I have been working on ASP.NET till now , which I know is pretty old now. So wanting to learn MVC and ASP.NET core.

Here I'm trying to create a login page in ASP.Net core , MVC web application.I have  a Login.cshtml page, where I have designed the page.It has 2 text boxes one for `username` ,one for `password` and a `Login` button. Upon click on `Login` button, I need to validate the credentials entered.

Till now in ASP.NET,I used to follow 2 methods.
Method 1  :   On button click event, connect to database using ADO.NET , get the username and password, match it with entered data and redirect it to home page if it matches.

Method 2 :After JQuery has become popular this is what I have been doing. On click of a button, write JQuery script to get the username and password from database (using WCF service) through the AJAX call and validate with the entered data. If it matches then it goes to the home page.

Now my question here is , should I call the action method in Controller and make a call to a Web API which gets data from database and validates or use JQuery here in the script section and call Web API.

I know this may be some basic question, but I want to know the best way (performance wise ,best practice wise and latest usage wises) of doing it.

**Note**

Web API is external to the web application project and not in the same solution.
The web API I'm developing is a rest API, if it is of any use mentioning here.

Comment: I just want to know the best practice to call web API from ASP.NET core MVC application. Once I know the which one is the best way, I will search how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
using(var client=new HttpClient()){
var baseUrl=string.Format("{0}://{1}",HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Schema,HttpContext,Current.Request.Url.Authority);
    var response=client.PostAsync(baseUrl+"/[]",content).result;
    var result=await response.Content.REadAsAsync<object>();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just want to be clear that you are suggesting to call API from controller method right?

Comment: If web api is hosting separately and secure then passing authorize header value also required.